# Type mismatch between ? and java.Object in Map<String,?> <==> map.put("str", new Object())

Tags: java, type-conversion

Can someone explain the following error (from eclipse IDE):

> The method put(String, capture#1-of ?)
>   in the type Map
>   is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String, Object)

Received on line 3 of the code blow:

```
public class MyTest {
    public void populateUserLoggedIn(Map<String, ?> model){
        model.put( "test", new Object() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` is not equivalent to `Object` for methods that take `?` as a parameter. With a `Map<String, ?>`, the signature of `put` is `put(String, ?)`. You can't pass anything but `null` for a `?` parameter.

Consider this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
myTest.populateUserLoggedIn(map);
Integer foo = map.get("test"); // ClassCastException
```

Since `populateUserLoggedIn` takes a `Map<String, ?>`, a map with any type of values can be passed in... so within the method you have no way of knowing what types are or aren't legal as values. Therefore, you cannot add any.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the values of `model` is undefined, so the compiler can't guarantee that a value of type `Object` will be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this [paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Wildcards):

> As an example of an unbounded wildcard, `List<?>` indicates a list which has an unknown
>   object type. Methods which take such a list as an argument can take any type of list, 
>   regardless of parameter type. Reading from the list will return objects of type `Object`,
>   and writing non-null elements to the list is not allowed, since the parameter type is
>   not known.